# Dropdown menu bug Close and Open Depending on Click area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have no idea why this is happening. 
I replicated a accordion with html, css and jquery, i followed this guide and i adapted it to my website
"http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Accordion-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/"

My jquery is the same, my html and css is a bit different because i customized it, but its basicly the same.

HTML:

```
<div class="plan-container" style="flex: 0 0 25%;">
  <div class="plan-header-mec">
    <h2 style="color: #fff; font-weight: lighter; margin: 0; padding-top: 0.625em;">Blabla</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="plan-details">
    <div class="accordion">
      <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1">
          <li class="fa fa-check">Title</li>
        </a>
        <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
          <p>Information.</p>
        </div>
        <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
      </div>
      <!--end .accordion-section-->

      <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2">
          <li class="fa fa-check">Title</li>
        </a>
        <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
          <p>Information</p>
        </div>
        <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
      </div>
      <!--end .accordion-section-->

      <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3">
          <li class="fa fa-check">Title</li>
        </a>
        <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
          <p>Information</p>
        </div>
        <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
      </div>
      <!--end .accordion-section-->

      <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-4">
          <li class="fa fa-check">Title</li>
        </a>
        <div id="accordion-4" class="accordion-section-content">
          <p>Information</p>
        </div>
        <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
      </div>
      <!--end .accordion-section-->

      <div class="accordion-section">
        <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-5">
          <li class="fa fa-check">Title</li>
        </a>
        <div id="accordion-5" class="accordion-section-content">
          <p>Information</p>
        </div>
        <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
      </div>
      <!--end .accordion-section-->
    </div>
    <!--end .accordion-->
    <p>Conclusion</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media handheld (min-width: 480px) {
  .plan-container {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .plan-container {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .plan-container {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}

.plan-container {
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.plan-container .plan-header-mec {
  padding: 50px 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background-image: url(../img/mv-ber-vantagens-mecanico.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
}

.plan-container .plan-header p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #447F71;
}

.plan-container .plan-details {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px;
  background: url("http://raventools.com/wp-content/themes/raven-wp-theme-2014/images/plan-bottom-border.png") top center no-repeat;
}

.plan-container .plan-details ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.plan-container .plan-details ul li span {
  font-weight: lighter;
  /*color: #777777;*/
}

.plan-container .plan-details p {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 2em 0;
  padding: 1.25em;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #777777;
}


/* Test accordion */

.accordion,
.accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  background-image: url(../img/fibra-carbono.jpg);
}


/*----- Section Titles -----*/

.accordion-section-title {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333333;
  /*Carbon Fiber Background*/
  /*Carbon Fiber Background*/
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  /* Type */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
}


/*.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
        background:#4c4c4c;
    }*/

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}


/*----- Section Content -----*/

.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}


/* Test accordion */


/* Check Mark Color*/

.fa ul {
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.fa-check {
  display: block;
}

.fa-check::before {
  color: #66ff33;
}


/* Check Mark Color*/
```

And finally my jQuery

```
/*Accordion*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
  }

  $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(e.target).is('.active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      close_accordion_section();
      // Add active class to section title
      $(this).addClass('active');
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Ok now, my problem is. What i want is:
When i click Title 1, Information 1 dropdown. (works)
If i click Title 2. while information 1 is showing, information 1 closes and opens information 2 (works)

Now my problem is, if Information 2 is open and i want to close it, when i click on the Title, on the letters of the tittle the dropdown closes and opens again... If i click outside the letters it works properly.

In the jquery

```
if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
```

I changed the `e.target` to `.accordion-section-title` and what happends is, it opens and closes when i click anywhere, letters or outside the letters, but if a information box is openned and i click on another one, the other one doesn't open, but the opened one closes.

I have no idea what else to do, if you can help, i would apreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your **e.target** sometimes is the wrong element, infact it depends on where you actually click on.

For instance, if you click on a child element (like the `<li>` element in your case) the condition `$(e.target).is('.active')` will fail

Try with this code instead:

```
 $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var target = $(e.target).closest(".accordion-section-title");
    var currentAttrValue = $(target).attr('href');

    if($(target).is('.active')) {
```

Comment: Wow i can't believe that worked. So simple!
I never thought of that, so basicly, what you did was make the e.target get the closes title so it would never get the wrong element, right?

Comment: @Kinder, yes, it is the safest way to get the correct element

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer (not yet 50 reputation so I can't comment, sorry), but is there any (good ?) reason to not using [JQueryUI accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) ?
If you don't want to use all the jQueryUI (and I can understand) you can "isolate" just the accordion pluggin on the custom download section.
I may be simplest than what you're trying to write imho.

Comment: Well tbh, i was in kind of a hurry when i did this, and i found that and i tried to use it and i didn't know how. So i thought it would be faster for me to replicate it then spend time learning how to use it.